# Keycloak single logout with Django

Tags: django, openid, keycloak

I created a Django application that integrates with Keycloak's OpenID authentication. So far the only pressing issue I've encounted is the logout function.

When I log out via the Django app, I could implement it such that it logs the user out of the Keycloak as well. However, I could not find a way to perform the reverse. Logging out via Keycloak account management interface does not log the user out from the Django app. This means that the user can still remain authenticated on the Django app even though he is already logged out of Keycloak, which appears to be a security concern.

From what I understood from most other similar StackOverflow post, Keycloak supposedly has a way to call back to web application to logout the user, but however it is not very clearly documented on how to implement it:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#admin-url-configuration

Does anyone have any idea how this can be implemented on django?

I used Django 2.1 + mozilla-django-oidc package.